# IFELSE in R returning incorrect values

Tags: r, if-statement

I have a data frame with categorical values that were entered manually and there are several mistakes. Someone cleaned up the bad data and I loaded that into R and merged that with the rest of my data. Everything so far is good.

As an example, let's say this is the data I have with the original (mix of good and bad data) in the "Value" column and the corrections of the bad data in the "Value_Clean" column. Obviously this is a small example but my actual data frame has dozens of corrections of different values and several thousand rows.

```
test <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3)
               , Value = c("Discuss plan", "Discuss plan", "Discuss paln")
               , Value_Clean = c(NA, NA, "Discuss plan"))
```

I would like to create a new column called "Value_Final" that has "Discuss plan" for IDs 1, 2, and 3.

It seems pretty straightforward that I should be able to accomplish this with an ifelse:

```
test$Value_Final <- ifelse(is.na(test$Value_Clean), test$Value, test$Value_Clean)
```

However, when I do that I get the following:

```
> test
  ID        Value  Value_Clean Value_Final
1  1 Discuss plan         <NA>           2
2  2 Discuss plan         <NA>           2
3  3 Discuss paln Discuss plan           1
```

What the hell? I feel like I've done similar things with ifelse in R without running into this issue, so what is going?

Thanks!

Comment: Please change the datatype to character to get your result 
test$Value_Clean = as.character(test$Value_Clean)
test$Value = as.character(test$Value)

test$Value_Final <- ifelse(is.na(test$Value_Clean), test$Value, test$Value_Clean)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a case of `factor` coercing to integer storage value.  Can be corrected with `stringsAsFactors = FALSE` while creating the `data.frame`

```
test <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 2, 3)
                , Value = c("Discuss plan", "Discuss plan", "Discuss paln")
                , Value_Clean = c(NA, NA, "Discuss plan"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
ifelse(is.na(test$Value_Clean), test$Value, test$Value_Clean)
#[1] "Discuss plan" "Discuss plan" "Discuss plan"
```

---

Or if the data is already created, then can convert to `character` with `as.character`

```
test[1:2] <- lapply(test[1:2], as.character)
```

Or do this within the `ifelse`

```
ifelse(is.na(test$Value_Clean), as.character(test$Value), 
         as.character(test$Value_Clean))
```

Answer (score 3):

The dplyr version of ifelse doesn't have this issue

```
ifelse(is.na(test$Value_Clean), test$Value, test$Value_Clean)

# [1] 2 2 1


dplyr::if_else(is.na(test$Value_Clean), test$Value, test$Value_Clean)

# [1] Discuss plan Discuss plan Discuss plan
# Levels: Discuss paln Discuss plan
```

FYI for this particular example you might use coalesce instead

```
dplyr::coalesce(test$Value_Clean, test$Value)
# [1] Discuss plan Discuss plan Discuss plan
# Levels: Discuss plan
```

Comment: this is all very helpful and thank you for the tip about coalesce!

Answer (score 1):

you could try dplyr and tibbles as an alternative:

```
library(dplyr)

tibble(ID = c(1, 2, 3)
       , Value = c("Discuss plan", "Discuss plan", "Discuss plan")
       , Value_Clean = c(NA, NA, "Discuss plan")) %>% 
  mutate(Value_Final = ifelse(is.na(Value_Clean), Value, Value_Clean))
```

tibbles don't convert character columns to factors per default, which comes in handy in many many cases

Edit:
use `as_tibble(dataframe)` to convert an existing dataframe to a tibble

Comment: Note that `as_tibble` will not convert the factors to character, so you'd still get numeric output for the `ifelse` here